# sqlite query with string parameter xcode

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am trying to query my sqlite database where a column is equal to a value passed to the function.

My query looks like this

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT rowid, name FROM Coops WHERE category=%@",chosenCategory];
```

This query returns nothing but if I change it so it looks like this

```
query=@"SELECT rowid, name FROM Coops WHERE category='the category I am passing';
```

It works just fine.  My question is how do you pass a string parameter to an sqlite query in xcode.

My entire method is this

-(NSArray *)coopsInCategory:(NSString *)chosenCategory
{

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT rowid, name, hCity, hours  FROM Coops WHERE category=%@",chosenCategory];


/*if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error preparing statment",sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
}*/





 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            int uniqueId=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *nameChar=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            char *hCityChar=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

            char *hoursChar=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);

            NSString *name=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChar];

            NSString *hCity=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:hCityChar];

            NSString *hours=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:hoursChar];



            informationObject *info=[[informationObject alloc]coopDetails:uniqueId name:name hCity:hCity hours:hours];



            [retval addObject:info];

            [name release];


            [hCity release];

            [hours release];

        }

     sqlite3_finalize(statement);
 }
return retval;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need single quotes around the `%@`. If that's not it, try to trace down what the error message is.

Comment: I did try using '%@' but it is still coming up with an empty query.  There are no error messages

Comment: There must be some kind of error message, or otherwise your query is really returning an empty set. Do you have something like this in your code?: `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
   NSAssert1(0,@"Error preparing statement",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
`

Comment: In place of the sql parameter, try [query UTF8String].

Comment: Do you mean category=%@,[chosenCategory UTF8String]

Comment: I mean `sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)` where 'query' is your NSString from your question.